# Add img to td after td clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with one row, with one cell, that has a text. the text is in the center of the td.

while clicking the td, I want to add an image after the text. I don't want that the text will be moved, but will be stay in the same place.

this is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/L7qn3/1/

in this jsfiddle, the text moves left.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="border:1px solid red; width:100px; text-align:center;" onclick="func(this);">
            sfh
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

thank you all!

Comment: When center aligning the text, it *will* move when you add more content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is by giving the text a fixed margin instead of centring it. That way the text will stay centred when new content is added.

```
<td style="border:1px solid red; width:100px;" onclick="func(this);">
    <span style="margin-left:38px;">sfh</span>
</td>
```

Here's the example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7qn3/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to place script tag before the table, otherwise browser can't find the function since function is declared afterwards.. 
Here is working example [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RJ3WR/)

```
<script>
    function func(elem) {
    elem.innerHTML += "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,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'>"
}
</script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="border:1px solid red; width:100px; text-align:center;" onclick="func(this);">
            sfh
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```